# Get a value from dropdown selected in jquery

Tags: php, jquery

Here is my dropdown box in php and html.

```
<select name="employee_id" id="employee_id">
    <option value="<?= echo $row['employee_id'];?>" selected disabled>
<?php 
    if(isset($row["employee_name"])) 
        echo $row["employee_name"]; 
    else 
        echo "Select an Option";
?>
    </option>
<?php 
    $employee_sql = "SELECT employee_id, employee_name 
                    FROM employees 
                    WHERE left= 0 
                    ORDER BY employee_name ASC";
    $employee_result = mysqli_query($conn,$employee_sql );
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($employee_result)) {
?>
    <option value="<?= $row["employee_id"];?>"><?= $row["employee_name"];?></option>
<?php 
    } 
?>
</select>
```

Here is my jquery to get a value from the above dropdown.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    employee_id= $("#employee_id").val();
    console.log(employee_id);
})
```

I would like to know why I get null if I don't select employee_id.

Do you happen to know how to get a value no matter what I select?

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thank you for your consideration.

Comment: That JS is running as SOON as the DOM is completed. That will be well before you get a chance to select anything in your dropdown

Comment: Look at the DUP it will show you how to run the JS when the dropdown is changed. By you selecting on of the options

Comment: @RiggsFolly I get a selected value in my jquery but the problem is when I select nothing, I get null. In this case, do I have to create a conditional statement?